# How can I determine the fire rating of my entry door?

Tags: doors

I am trying to determine the Fire Rating of the entry door to my condo.  The only label on the door has the following:  A 111389  2688  S5712

Comment: What is the door made of?

Answer (score 1):

3 hours, according to [this information](http://archtoolbox.com/materials-systems/doors-windows/21-doorlabel.html).

> [image]